# Error creating TLS config (v1.3.7)

Tags: ssl, docker, ssl-certificate, docker-compose, traefik

I've been fiddling with Traefik for a few hours and find it extremely interesting. However, I've ran into a problem that I can't seem to solve by myself.

It's a very simple setup, just trying to test the HTTP to HTTPS redirection and my SSL certificates.

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

    services:
      traefik:
        image: traefik:v1.3.7-alpine
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
          - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:z
          - /opt/dockerapp/rocketchat/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml:ro,z
          - /opt/dockerapp/rocketchat/traefik/ssl:/etc/traefik/ssl/:ro,z
        command: --logLevel=DEBUG
```

My `traefik.toml` is

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
        CertFile = "ssl/mycert.pem"
        KeyFile = "ssl/mycert.key"
[docker]
domain = "docker.local"
watch = true

[web]
address = ":8080"
```

However, when I try to run it:

```
docker-compose up
Starting rocketchat_traefik_1
Attaching to rocketchat_traefik_1
traefik_1  | time="2017-08-29T13:45:55Z" level=info msg="Traefik version v1.3.7 built on 2017-08-25_08:56:06PM" 
traefik_1  | time="2017-08-29T13:45:55Z" level=info msg="Using TOML configuration file /etc/traefik/traefik.toml" 
traefik_1  | time="2017-08-29T13:45:55Z" level=debug msg="Global configuration loaded {"GraceTimeOut":10000000000,"Debug":false,"CheckNewVersion":true,"AccessLogsFile":"","TraefikLogsFile":"","LogLevel":"DEBUG","EntryPoints":{"http":{"Network":"","Address":":80","TLS":null,"Redirect":{"EntryPoint":"https","Regex":"","Replacement":""},"Auth":null,"Compress":false},"https":{"Network":"","Address":":443","TLS":{"MinVersion":"","CipherSuites":null,"Certificates":[{"CertFile":"ssl/mycert.pem","KeyFile":"ssl/mycert.key"}],"ClientCAFiles":null},"Redirect":null,"Auth":null,"Compress":false}},"Cluster":null,"Constraints":[],"ACME":null,"DefaultEntryPoints":["http","https"],"ProvidersThrottleDuration":2000000000,"MaxIdleConnsPerHost":200,"IdleTimeout":180000000000,"InsecureSkipVerify":false,"Retry":null,"HealthCheck":{"Interval":30000000000},"Docker":{"Watch":true,"Filename":"","Constraints":null,"Endpoint":"unix:///var/run/docker.sock","Domain":"docker.local","TLS":null,"ExposedByDefault":true,"UseBindPortIP":false,"SwarmMode":false},"File":null,"Web":{"Address":":8080","CertFile":"","KeyFile":"","ReadOnly":false,"Statistics":null,"Metrics":null,"Path":"","Auth":null},"Marathon":null,"Consul":null,"ConsulCatalog":null,"Etcd":null,"Zookeeper":null,"Boltdb":null,"Kubernetes":null,"Mesos":null,"Eureka":null,"ECS":null,"Rancher":null,"DynamoDB":null}" 
traefik_1  | time="2017-08-29T13:45:55Z" level=info msg="Preparing server http &{Network: Address::80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:0xc4202f4ea0 Auth:<nil> Compress:false}" 
traefik_1  | time="2017-08-29T13:45:55Z" level=info msg="Preparing server https &{Network: Address::443 TLS:0xc42032c000 Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> Compress:false}" 
traefik_1  | time="2017-08-29T13:45:55Z" level=error msg="Error creating TLS config: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input" 
traefik_1  | time="2017-08-29T13:45:55Z" level=fatal msg="Error preparing server: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input" 
rocketchat_traefik_1 exited with code 1
```

Which seems to indicate there's something wrong with my certificate. I know for sure the certificate is fine, it's a wildcard certificate we're using successfully with Apache and NGINX.

I've already checked [this possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45826786/error-creating-tls-config-after-updating-traefik-to-v1-3-6), but both the certificate and the private key match those parameters.

Can anybody shed some light?

Thanks!

Comment: try setting an absolute path for CertFile and KeyFile

Comment: And that solves my problem! If you add it as an answer I'll be happy to accept it :)

Comment: great! glad I could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like traefik is not finding your certificates.
Try putting an absolute path for CertFile and KeyFile such as:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
        CertFile = "/etc/traefik/ssl/mycert.pem"
        KeyFile = "/etc/traefik/ssl/mycert.key"
[docker]
domain = "docker.local"
watch = true

[web]
address = ":8080"
```